# Multiclass Classifier comparison decision regions

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, multiclass-classification, matplotlib

How can I get the very same effect of this tutorial in [Scikit Documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/classification/plot_classifier_comparison.html#sphx-glr-download-auto-examples-classification-plot-classifier-comparison-py) with more than 2 classes?
Let's say we'll keep only the first dataset (the linear separable one) and substitute it with `n_classes=3` like in the following snippet:

```py
X, y = make_classification(n_features=2, n_redundant=0, n_informative=2,
                          random_state=1, n_clusters_per_class=1, n_classes=3)
rng = np.random.RandomState(2)
X += 2 * rng.uniform(size=X.shape)
linearly_separable = (X, y)

datasets = [linearly_separable]
```

I'd like to get the very same effect with plotted the probabilities in a colormap.

Thank you!

Comment: What was wrong with your suggestion?